# How to create a Cylindrical design pattern like this in XmL in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three images bottom cap, Cyclinder and top head. I can't align them as in my image. I need some help for doing this thing but in vain. Here is the Image.

[image: sample]

I'm trying to do this thing in this way. Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cap_cylinder"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_cylinder"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/blue_cap_cylinder"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to do this. I just need a single complete design implementation.

Comment: Draw on your canvas. A custom View might be what you need. I mean, stretching dynamically based on the percentage value.

Comment: Which type of customview. i never did it before. Can you explain or some example

Comment: YOUR custom View. Explaining how to here would be too broad. Basically, you have to redraw the View contents at each cycle, so that it reacts instantly to the changes of its exposed parameters.

Comment: You can use Horizontal Progress bar with custom background resource.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a graphic designer who provides these images?  They need to provide you with a *nine-patch* image file.  Show them this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

This is what you will use for the "stretchable" column image.

So say you have one bitmap for the base, and a nine-patch bitmap for the stretchable column.  Then you create a `LayerDrawable` in XML that contains a `ScaleDrawable` that scales the column to the correct height.

base_and_column.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/base"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/base"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/column"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/column"/>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now you can use this drawable as a background, and you don't even need an `ImageView`:

```
        <View
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/base_and_column"
```

To set the size, you just set the level of the background drawable:

```
       // drawable levels go from 0 to 10000
       columnView.getBackgroundDrawable().setLevel(percent * 100);
```

For the daily/weekly/monthly text, you can use a `FrameLayout` to overlay a `TextView` on top of your column view.

You can have three different drawables one for each color, or you could use `Drawable.setColorFilter()` to take a neutral-colored column and tint it blue, green, or orange:

```
        Drawable column = ((LayerDrawable) columnView.getBackgroundDrawable()).findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.column);
        column.setColorFilter(backgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```